Each branch of $\sqrt{z}$ can be continued analytically along any path in $\mathbb{c}-0$
I am trying to show the following:
Each branch of $\sqrt{z}$ can be continued analytically along any path in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, but cannot be continued along any path containing $0\in \mathbb{C}$.
I know the definition of what it means for a function to be analytically continuable along a curve:
$f(z)$ is analytically continuable along $\gamma$ if for each $t\in [a,b]$ there is a convergent power series $f_t(z) = \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a_n(t)(z-\gamma(t))^n, |z-\gamma(t)|<r(t)$ such that $f_a(z)$ is the power series representing f(z) at z_0, and when $s$ is near $t$, then $f_s(z) = f_t(z)$ for $z$ in the intersection of the disks of convergence.
but it seems like I am stuck in how to apply it in this case (if this indeed is the right approach).
I would appreciate any hints or suggestions. Thanks.

Consider the analytic continuation of the branches of the square root function. The choice of the branch for the argument of z determines a branch of √z. For polar form of z, we have $z = re^{i\theta}$, and for θ restricted to an interval of length $2π$, a branch is given by $f(z) = √r e^{iθ/2}$.
Let path $\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C} - {0}$ be arbitrary. Since $\gamma$ avoids the origin, there exists a continuous branch of the argument along the path, which we denote by $\theta(t)$. Thus, we have $\gamma(t) = |\gamma(t)|e^{i\theta(t)}$. Around each point $\gamma(t)$, we have a local power series representation.
$$f_t(z) = \sqrt{|\gamma(t)|} e^{i\theta(t)/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n} \left(\frac{z-\gamma(t)}{\gamma(t)}\right)^n.$$
The continuity of $\theta(t)$ gives us that the coefficients in this series are continuous functions of $t$. For $s$ close to $t$, $f_s(z)$ and $f_t(z)$ agree on the intersection of their disks of convergence. We have therefore proven analytic continuation along $\gamma$.
Think of now a loop $\gamma$ winding once around the origin, that starts and ends at $z_0 = re^{i\theta_0}$. We may, without loss of generality, assume that we start on the principal branch, which satisfies $-\pi < \theta_0 \le \pi$. As we traverse $\gamma$, the argument changes continuously. Thus, after one loop, the argument will have increased (or decreased) by $2\pi$.
We have $f(z_0) = \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta_0/2}$. When we go around $\gamma$ and return to $z_0$, the argument is $\theta_0 + 2\pi$, and the value that has been analytically continued at $z_0$ is $\sqrt{r}e^{i(\theta_0+2\pi)/2} = -\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta_0/2} = -f(z_0)$. The change of sign here shows that analytic continuation along a loop around the origin gives a different branch. The original branch cannot be continued analytically along such a path.
The core problem is that no continuous argument function can be defined in any neighborhood of the origin. This fact prevents any branch of $\sqrt{z}$ from being analytically continued along a path that crosses $0$.
